# Graphs with many positive eigenvalues of their distance matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple connected graph $D(G)$ its *distance matrix* and $n_{+}(G), n_{-}(G)$ the number of positive and negative eigenvalues of $D(G)$ respectively.

We call a graph $G$ *optimistic* if $n_{+}(G) > n_{-}(G).$ The notion being motivated by a [remark](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/78_12_matrix_polynomials.pdf&ei=tb1KUuvPNubm4QT3loDgDw&usg=AFQjCNForRfme5huW7H47YBzw8OouvanHg&sig2=wf5VhX6SUvVgicgeDRJ_pg&bvm=bv.53371865,d.bGE) of Graham and Lovász saying that is not known if such graphs exists.

A computer search indicates that there is no optimistic graph on up to 11 vertices. Yet it can be [easily seen](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4517) that the *Paley* graphs of order $n > 13$ have this property. More generally every conference graph does and there are many other examples of optimistic graphs as well.

The question that remains is

> Is there any optimistic graph of order $12$? If not is the Paley graph of order $13$ the unique smallest optimistic graph?

My computational resources are just slightly too low to tackle this by a computer program while my intellect is way out to be able to reduce the search space or construct an example by hand.

Hence I leave it here in case anyone can run a computer program or suggest some reductions on the search space.

**Edit 1.** The distance matrix $D = (d_{i,j})$ of a connected graph with vertex set $_1,\ldots,v_n$ is the matrix whose entries are $d_{i,j} = d(v_i,v_j)$

**Edit 2.** In case someone has a powerful enough machine, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fw8fkklce63n06g/findIt.sage) is a small Sage program searching for optimistic graphs. The best way to run it 
is in parallel in the following  way

> geng -c 12 12:0 |  parallel --block 100M --pipe  sage findIt.sage

Comment: could you please include a definition of this "distance matrix" --- I'm familiar with a few notions but am not sure which one is meant here. Thanks!

Comment: as a followup: what is "d(x,y)"? An arbitrary metric, or is the vertex set embedded into Euclidean space? or is it the shortest path length from $x$ to $y$?

Comment: Couldn't find regular graph on 12 vertices for a start.

Comment: @survit $d(x,y)$ is the length of the shortest x-y path.

Comment: joro: use McKay's geng to get regular graphs on 12 vertices.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil I used exactly nauty's geng.

Comment: Joro; I misunderstood your comment, I realize now.